# Currying functions with format dependent types

Tags: f#

As far as I'm aware, F# doesn't handle printfn like it does other functions because of it's type dependence on the string parameter. Could someone explain to me why that prevents me from doing

```
let printn = printfn "%A"
```

The error says the type is infered to `('a -> unit)` and that I need to add an explicit parameter or a type annotation. Why? I'm perfectly fine with the type it inferred it to. Also, if I add an explicit point, it still has the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `printn` would be a simple value the way you define it. And values can't be generic in the .NET runtime.

Make the parameter explicit so it is a function:

```
let printn value = printfn "%A" value
```

For more information, see the topic [Value Restriction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I'm confused. How does `printfn` work at all then? How do I pass in a second parameter if it only takes one and returns a value?